# Exceeding largest datatype allowed on chipset. C++

Tags: c++, types, embedded

I have some math that is exceeding the c++ long data type. What would be the best way to get around this? I am doing basic math +,/,and* on an embedded chipset.  I am adding up numbers in a loop and dividing the large number afterwards.

Comment: Look into bignum libraries. There's a few floating around, here's one: https://github.com/melwilson/bignum-embedded.  I think GNU has one although I'm not sure if it's optimized for embedded or not.

Comment: I have used and like gmpxx.h

Answer (score 5):

Usually, a `long` (identical to `long int`) is at least 4 bytes in size. But, check for yourself. If you find that `long long int` has more bytes than a `long int`, and if your values do not exceed the maximum value storable in a `long long int`, use that. use `#include <limits>` and use functions inside this header to determine the maximum values storable in integer types.

For example,

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long int>::max() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs the following on my machine:

```
2147483647
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775807
```

If, however, your values exceed what can be stored in a `long long int` also, use a big number library.

Comment: My system doesn't have a higher value for it. Is there another good trick to represent numbers in a way that I can still break it up and divide outside the loop without much overhead?

Comment: If you can't fit your numbers into long long, and if you still need to do arithmetic operations on them, you will need to use a bignum library. Don't try writing a bignum class by yourself, find one that suits your platform.